# What is the command to use to put your computer to sleep (not hibernate)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I want to put my Windows PC (Windows 7) into a sleep state via command line (so I can bind to macro button on keyboard).

The power button on the PC is setup to but the computer to sleep (but it's down on the floor and I'm too lazy to reach down) it exactly how I want it (sleeps using hybrid mode in case I loose power)

The sleep command on the shutdown menu also works.

most info I found says to use;

```
%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe PowrProf.dll, SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

But this puts the computer in hibernate mode.  I do have hibernate disabled but using hybrid sleep.

So, What is the command to use to put your computer to sleep (not hibernate)?

Comment: `rundll32.exe PowrProf.dll,SetSuspendState` is not recommended. It is dangerous. (Because it corrupts the stack, as it does [not](http://superuser.com/a/331545/21887) comply with the function signature [demanded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3207411/234309) by `Rundll32`. Then unforeseeable bad things may happen, as Raymond Chen [warns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx)…)

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a solution.  I installed a freeware program called AutoHotKey and recorded the steps to invoke Start Menu -> Sleep into a script file.  Then I complied the script file into a stand-alone executable SleepWin7.exe.

Now I simply run SleepWin7.exe to put my computer into hybrid sleep.

You may uninstall AutoHotKey if this is all you need it for.

---

Update: The above solution doesn't work when the user isn't logged in, i.e. Windows 7 Login Screen.  (My computer wakes up at 4am every Sunday to perform weekly backup, which is done without user login.)  In such case, the [Wizmo](http://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm) program still works:

> wizmo.exe quiet standby!

Comment: Here is an AutoHotKey script (using keyboard); 

Send, {LWINDOWN}{LWINUP}
WinWait, Start menu, 
IfWinNotActive, Start menu, , WinActivate, Start menu, 
WinWaitActive, Start menu, 
Send, {TAB}{UP}{RIGHT}s

Comment: This is the solution that I ended up using. as it supports the hybrid sleep.

Comment: +1 This feels dirty but it works. I had to change the last Send part to: "Send, {RIGHT}{RIGHT}s". BTW I almost gave you a -1 for recommending to uninstall AHK, as that would be unforgivable :)

Comment: I also added this to the start of the script to ensure the commands go to the desktop window, and prevent them getting lost: WinActivate, ahk_class Progman

Comment: +1 to demoncodemonkey for threatening -1 on uninstalling AHK.

Comment: +1 Not the cleanest/ideal solution, since one would expect that there is a windows command-line feature to do the same, but it works like a charm. BTW: I have been looking allover for the Windows equivalent and all I found was this: C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0 - which doesn't do exactly the same. So thumbs up for a solution that works!

Comment: The `!` in `wizmo.exe quiet standby!` enforces the StandBy even if applications object. `quiet` suppresses arguably annoying beeps by `wizmo.exe`. (In case someone wondered.)

Comment: After switching to Windows 8, I'm now using NirCmd (very light weight) and it puts the computer to hybrid sleep; `nircmd.exe standby` more info can be found here -> http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

Comment: you may need to right click and do 'Unblock' on the exe under 'Advanced'

Answer (score 73):

Hope you find these useful.

Shutdown    `%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -s`

Reboot          `%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -r`

Logoff          `%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -l`

Standby         `%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Standby`

Hibernate      `%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Hibernate`

Caution: [rundll32.exe should not be used to launch powerprof.dll](http://superuser.com/a/331545/21887). 
Instead you should call SetSuspendState directly. This can be done using Powershell - create a file eg sleep.ps1, with the below contents.

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState("Suspend", $false, $true)
```

Then run it using `powershell -File C:\your-path\sleep.ps1`. You may first need to run the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` to enable powershell scripts to run.

The above script causes a system suspend, which will either sleep or hibernate depending on your current hibernate setting. To change that setting from the command line, run `powercfg -h off` (or `on`) from the command line as administrator.

Comment: whoa nice! +1...

Comment: +1 All of them needs to be executed from elevated command prompt in Windows 7

Comment: This is great but where's the one for Sleeeeeeeeeeeeep

Comment: Standby shortcut put my Win7 machine to hibernate :(

Comment: @demoncodemonkey: Standbyyyyyyyyyyyyy = Sleeeeeeeeeeeeep :)

Comment: Does `powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState` comply with the function signature [demanded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3207411/234309) by Rundll32? Otherwise unforeseeable bad things may happen, as Raymond Chen [warns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx)…

Comment: Apparently it does not: http://superuser.com/a/331545/21887 So it is considered dangerous to use this method and not recommended. (It corrupts the stack.)

Comment: %windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -h   to hibernate.

Comment: standby does not equal sleep on my system, it puts it in hibernation

Answer (score 16):

See the free utility of [Wizmo](http://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm), which can do very many things.
The command you're looking for is probably:

> wizmo standby

Comment: Wizmo looks pretty cool! Almost makes me wish I wasn't a mac fanboy

Comment: The utility doesn't need to be installed. Nice simple tool.

Comment: `wizmo.exe quiet standby` suppresses arguably annoying beeps by `wizmo.exe`.

Answer (score 14):

You can create a file with extension .ps1 (powershell) like "sleep.ps1" and write this:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState("Suspend", $false, $true)
```

I use this when I have something running and have to leave the pc and don't want to turn it off. So I change the script to look like this:

```
$minutes = read-host "Enter minutes to wait until sleep";
$secs= 60*$minutes;
Start-sleep -s $secs

Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState("Suspend", $false, $true)
```

And now when I run it, I just enter the minutes I want to wait until sleep.

You can run this from the cmd line by writing

```
powershell -File C:\your-path\sleep.ps1
```

If you've never run a PowerShell script before, you'll want to first run

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

in PowerShell to enable script running. This only has to be run once.

Comment: Aren't your variables' names backwards?

Answer (score 10):

With **Sysinternals PsTools** [[download](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip)]:

```
psshutdown -d
```

using the Command Line tool [PsShutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541).

<sub>(You might prefer this solution if you already have downloaded PsTools, it's pretty widely used. Other than that, this approach is equivalent to using [`wizmo`](http://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm)`quiet standby`.)</sub>

<sub>Source: https://superuser.com/a/331545/21887</sub>

Answer (score 7):

I've been using this [SLEEP.EXE](http://www.gammadyne.com/cmdline.htm#sleep) utility for years. It works well, and you don't have to remember what arguments to give it for suspend mode (its default form of "sleep").

Comment: [SLEEP.EXE](http://www.gammadyne.com/cmdline.htm#sleep) works for me, on Windows 7 Pro SP1.  The parent page also lists many other useful-looking command line tools for Windows.  Thanks, @jjlin!

Answer (score 6):

to disable hibernate mode you need to use

```
powercfg -h off
```

now, **rundll32 powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState** will put your station in stanby mode

**[EDIT]**

actually I can't setup for an hybrid sleep because I have a laptop (a state that is not available on mobile stations), for hybrid sleep you need to have hibernation enabled and some say that rundll32 powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState trigger the default sleep mode in your control-panel\power-management settings. please try if **rundll32 powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState hybrid sleep** give some results.

Comment: This also disables hybrid sleep, so it kinda defeats the purpose

Comment: rundll32 powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState hybrid sleep still put the computer into hibernation.  thanks for the idea.

Comment: rundll32 is not designed for calling SetSuspendState, so it gets wrong parameter values. That's why it always cause hibernation if you have not disabled it intentionally.

Answer (score 5):

Make a bat file, where 600 is delay in seconds.

ping -n 600 -w 1 127.0.0.1 > nul

powercfg -h off

%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Standby

Comment: Great way to put the computer to sleep, and very easy to send someone else who wants to have sheduled sleep.

Comment: Creative answer!

Comment: Don't use rundll32.exe to call SetSuspendState: it is not designed for that. See explanations [here](http://superuser.com/questions/331542/sleep-shortcut-in-win7/331545#331545)

Answer (score 4):

If you're competent with compiling a .NET program the following [command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setsuspendstate.aspx) will do this

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, 
                                                 false,   /* force */
                                                 true     /* disableWake */);
```

**Note:** You do not need to disable hibernation as is required by the `rundll32 powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState` command. You can also use `PowerState.Hibernate` which will hibernate the machine if you want.

You could easily compile an EXE with this command with any version of [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CS). Just create a console application and add a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` DLL.

Comment: Wizmo cited above basically has already done this - using it seems like the equivalent. And it's written by Steve Gibson and free, so probably better than what I'd get hand coding the same thing!

Comment: +1. Looking for something like this here http://superuser.com/q/310045/84229

Comment: You don't even have to use `Visual Studio` to compile. Instead, the command-line compiler `csc.exe` could be used. It is already installed in all modern versions of Windows.