# Turn off monitor from windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn off display in Windows 7 without additional software](https://superuser.com/questions/321342/turn-off-display-in-windows-7-without-additional-software)

Windows has a way to turn off the display after a period of time.  But I want to run a scheduled task to turn off the display at a set time every night using the command line.

This is the UI for turning off the display using the timer
[image]

Is there a command to turn off the display using the command line?

Comment: Would using third-party applications be okay?  I can recommend a good one if you're okay with that.  (I don't know that this can be done from the command shell without installing a bunch of stuff anyway.)

Comment: @hamed If you're going to say he is asking a duplicate question, don't dupe the dude above you and post the same link.

Comment: @Raystafarian the other question has not yet been answered, so I think there is some value.  A blank screen saver is not the same as turning off the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this: http://forums.techarena.in/monitor-video-cards/1378029.htm#post5131376

You can make a shortcut using `POWERCFG -Change -monitor-timeout-ac 1` as the location, then create a scheduled task to run the shortcut at a specific time. Just keep the "1" which is the time delay for how long until the screen turns off, then just have the scheduled task run one minute earlier than you want the screen to turn off.

The above link gives more of an explanation of what you can do/change with the command.

I JUST tested exactly the command i listed above, and even with my normal power settings to NEVER turn off my display, after running the shortcut and a quick minute later, my monitor went dark, a quick shake of the mouse brought it back. BUT, this SETS the timeout to turn off your monitor, so you may want another scheduled task to change it back to your normal whenever you normally get back onto your computer.

Comment: Do oyu know if the ac/dc is for AC or DC power, or something else? =p

Comment: AC = mains power, DC = battery

Comment: One of the comments in the linked threat says this workaround is necessary because turning off the monitor is not possible in Windows 7.