# How to black out second monitor when playing a full screen game?

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, fullscreen, imac, gaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn off display in Windows 7 without additional software](https://superuser.com/questions/321342/turn-off-display-in-windows-7-without-additional-software)

I've got two monitors. When I play a full screen game in my primary monitor, the second monitor still shows the Windows desktop. How can I black out the second monitor so that it doesn't show anything at all? My graphics card is from ATI.

I'm running Windows 7 in Boot Camp on an iMac. I don't know if this makes a difference, however, as any solution to my question will do, really. For instance, is there a tiny app that I could run to disable the second monitor for a while? I'd rather not have to open Windows display settings every time I run a game and disable the monitor that way, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've said "any solution will do" and you want something simpler than disabling the monitor via Windows display settings... I propose the following.

Push the little button in the lower right hand corner of the second monitor that looks like this:    (|)   ...It'll turn off the power to that monitor, blacking it out.