# timed television controls

Tags: windows-7, script, automation, desktop-computer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn off display in Windows 7 without additional software](https://superuser.com/questions/321342/turn-off-display-in-windows-7-without-additional-software)

In the office we have a wall mounted television connected to a PC that is always on.

Is there a way to have some sort of script/Program that will automatically turn the screen on and off at the start/end of the day?

Comment: I would assume that that is largely dependent on the actual TV device.

Comment: yeah well it is connected via HDMI so i was wondering if there is something i can use/ try to see if it is possible or not?

Comment: @dizzytri99er - You won't be able turn the television off through a HDMI connection.  You can tell the PC to turn its monitor off ( the television ) I suppose after a period of time.