# is there a way to quickly turn one monitor off in a dualhead-setup with Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I want to create something like a macro that turns off one of my monitors. I got a dualhead-setup and when i watch movies or play computer games, i want to turn one monitor off (standby) with something like a key-shortcut.

are there native possibilities integrated in Windows 10 to do something like this?
or do i need additional software - and if so, which software would you recommend?

thanks for any help!

**edit:**
the reason why I can't just turn off my monitor: 
[image]

Comment: Perhaps also check out: [Turn off display in Windows on command](http://superuser.com/questions/321342/turn-off-display-in-windows-on-command)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit `Windows` + `P` and select `Second Screen Only`. Once done, reverse the process and select `Duplicate` or `Extend`; depending on your preference/configuration.

[image]

Comment: wow, I did not expect that there is something like this build into windows 10. plus such a fast answer! thank you! will accept as soon as i can!

Comment: It has been around since Windows Vista/7 mate! :)

Comment: cool - but I never needed it until now, that's why I don't know it, i guess :)

Comment: but like i just recognized: the downside is, that it collects all windows on the remaining monitor. so the setup before you "turn off" one monitor is kinda lost then... would be enough for me to "blacken out" the monitor, i guess. maybe I'll ask another question.

Comment: Yikes, there is always the power button on the monitor. :)

Comment: well, not on mine. that's the whole point of my question my monitor's power button is (literally) broken (not joking).

Comment: just added a photo of my broken button to my question ;)