# How do i disconnect particular screen in Windows via commad-line?

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, powershell

My setup are 3 screens, one TV 4k and two 1080p screens. I am looking for a simple, best would be native way of turning off and on particular screen.

This option can be found in `Display Settings`, however I would rather use cmd or PowerShell to do this kind of thing.

[image]

Basically, I want to be able to turn off and on the display via cmd or PowerShell or more precisely I want to switch between options `Disconnect this display` and `Extend desktop to this display` on my screen number `x`

I have done some research and there is command available in windows, however it only changes projection mode, not mode for particular screen - `%windir%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /external` and other arguments like `/extend` or `/clone`

Additionally i want to mention programs like `nircmd` - I am aware of this little app for years, however it doesn't solve this problem, so before you post "nircmd can do it", please read carefully what i want to achieve - Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off display in Windows on command](https://superuser.com/questions/321342/turn-off-display-in-windows-on-command)

Comment: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/turn-off-monitor-shortcut-command-windows/

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate as options there didn't help me. I am aware of programs like `nircmd` and `Wizmo`, but they don't work as i want them to work.
@Moab there is mention about powershell in your link, i will try to play with this and will let you know, thanks!

Comment: It looks like same thing, but via powershell. It's not what i am looking for. To be more precise, i want to turn display off in windows, so it does not send the signal, not the display itself.

Comment: To explain this further i will attach screenshots what happens when i choose `Disconnect this display` option from the screenshot in main post.
Options for resolution and the rest are blank ([ss1](https://i.imgur.com/k8CTUTo.png)) and display goes to the right on the setup screen despite being at the top before ([ss2](https://i.imgur.com/AvT9F7r.png))

Comment: I use Nirsoft for this:  nircommand\nircmd" monitor off . Make a batch file of it and run it when needed. I find this works just fine

Comment: As i mentioned before, nircmd doesn't work as i want it to work. I don't want to send "command" to switch off screens. I want to disconnect particular screen from Windows. I am sure this option is available, because Windows Setting dialog has this option (previous screenshots) - it must be either registry or powershell