# Sleep NOT hibernate?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I put the computer to sleep from Command Prompt/Run menu in Windows Vista?](https://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu-in-windows-vist)

What is the command that **exactly** duplicates the action of selecting *Sleep* in the Start->Shut Down menu.

All the tips and tricks  I can find (like `rundll32 powrprof.dll, Set SuspendState Standby`) puts the computer into **hibernation** and I have to push the power button for it to restart.

I want to be able to create a hotkey to duplicate what clicking on *Sleep* or pressing the *Sleep* key on the keyboard. (My new keyboard doesn't have a sleep button)

Comment: check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351861/how-to-initiate-standby-sleep-from-command-line)

Answer (score 3):

One of Microsoft's Sysinternals tool is [PsShutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541), it will do what you want by using the command `psshutdown -d -t 0` it will correctly sleep, *not hibernate*, a computer