# How to initiate a sleep operation without disabling hibernation on windows 7/8/10

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, sleep

How do I order my windows PC to enter on sleep mode without me having to disable hibernation?

This is not an answer because it requires disabling hibernation
[Is there a command line tool to put Windows 8 to sleep?](https://superuser.com/questions/463646/is-there-a-command-line-tool-to-put-windows-8-to-sleep)

Comment: Are we talking about a desktop or laptop?  Are we talking about `Windows 8` or `Windows 7`, I asked, because `Windows 8` changed a good amount of things, when it comes to the supported power states.

Comment: So which version of Windows?  How you accomplish and if its possible, will depend on the version, I can't answer a broad question.

Comment: I have a windows 7 laptop and a windows 8 laptop now. Soon, I'll buy a windows 10 laptop to replace the windows 7 one.