# Sleep Windows 10 using CMD (command prompt)

Tags: windows, sleep, vbscript, standby

All [suggested commands](https://superuser.com/questions/463646/is-there-a-command-line-tool-to-put-windows-8-to-sleep) for Windows XP/7/8 puts Windows 10 in hibernation (not in standby).

1. so, for Windows 10, how to put PC into from CMD (batch file)?
2. is there correct a keyboard combination (without "choosing this and that", just a direct keyboard combination)?

Comment: Only this solution helped me - http://superuser.com/a/1054793/249349

Comment: This is still a duplicate. The answer on the dupe even states, "It seems that sleeping a computer is problematic if hibernate is turned on. The command rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0 for sleep is correct - however, it will hibernate instead of sleep if you don't turn the hibernation off," and it even suggestions a solution - using [PsShutdown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541) which _does_ support either suspend (sleep) or hibernate.

Comment: and why my topic is closed? it is not duplicate! there is not solution!

Comment: How about `shutdown /h /f` from an elevated command prompt?? If it says you need to enable hibernation first, use `powercfg -h on` from an elevated command prompt first and then retry the first command.

Comment: Scott Chamberlain's solution didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

Comment: that doesnt make sleep,even if you have turned hibernate off

Comment: It does for me.

Comment: This hibernates my windows 10 rather than sleep; Even though hibernate is not enabled on my system.