# Make Windows 7 go to sleep after x seconds

Tags: windows-7, sleep, power-management

When I start a long-processing job just before going to sleep myself, I often run

```
shutdown -s -t 3600
```

so that the computer automatically shutdowns after 3600 seconds.

**How to do the same to ask the computer to go to sleep after x seconds?**

I tried

```
shutdown -h -t 60
```

but 1) it didn't even work and anyway 2) this would make computer go to hibernation, which I don't want (I prefer sleep mode).

Note: [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/463652/221041) doesn't solve the problem because it doesn't allow to specify a time before going to sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I make Windows 7 go to sleep after x seconds?

Use the following batch file, and run as an Adminstrator

```
@echo off
rem disable hibernate
powercfg -hibernate off
rem wait x seconds, eg 1 hour
timeout 3600 /nobreak
rem sleep
%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [powercfg](http://ss64.com/nt/powercfg.html) - Control power settings, configure Hibernate/Standby modes.
- [timeout](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) - Delay execution for a few seconds or minutes, for use within a batch file.

Comment: thanks. even if it's not vital I was looking for a one line command (i like the simplicity of `shutdown -s -t`). Is there no?

Comment: Also is `powercfg -hibernate off` permanent (I thought so) or should it be done after every reboot ?

Comment: @Basj I believe it is permanent (until you turn it on again), but it won't do any hard to turn it off if it is already off.

Answer (score 8):

A one-liner (based of DavidPostill's accepted answer):

```
timeout /T 3600 & rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

To be sure it works, you can try it like this:

```
timeout /t 10 & notepad
```

the Notepad should open after 10 seconds.

Important note: If you have `git` installed on your computer, its `bin` folder might be in the `PATH`, and doing `timeout` in the command line will run
`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\timeout.exe` instead of the default `C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe`! In this case you have to include the full path of `timeout`, in order to use the Windows timeout tool.

Comment: Unfortunately, after 1 hour, it didn't do anything, just went back to the prompt. If I run the command without the timeout, it does put my computer to hibernate.

Comment: @qwertzguy Please try `timeout /t 10 & notepad`, what happens?

Comment: it works, it opened notepad after 10 sec. Not sure why it didn't work with the 1 hour and sleep command.