# PC sleep command in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, sleep

How can I make a Windows 10 PC sleep from Command Prompt or PowerShell? For example, to shutdown PC we can use the following:

```
shutdown /s /f
```

or to hibernate...

```
shutdown /h /f
```

Is there any command like these to make computer sleep?

Comment: Hmm, and I was thinking it was a duplicate of [Is there a command line tool to put Windows... to sleep?](https://superuser.com/a/463652/401839) which is, itself, marked as a duplicate.

Comment: See this....https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-sleep-windows-10-from-the-command-line/

Comment: Run command as an administrator and run **psshutdown -d -t 0** to suspend the computer and make it sleep, more parameter could refer to this [Psshutdown](https://docs.microsoft.com/zh-cn/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown)