# Invoke S0 Sleep using Task Scheduler for all users

Tags: windows-10, sleep, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler, nircmd

I'm trying to get a Windows 10 Optiplex 7000 to go to sleep at 10pm every day. I installed nircmd and created a task in task scheduler to run a .bat file with the following command: `nircmd.exe monitor async_off`

Running this batch file manually (by double clicking it) works just fine. However, if I have the "Run whether user is logged on or not" option selected, and I try to run the task in task scheduler (by clicking the run button) it seems like nothing happens. The batch file *is* running; I can create files with the output of `echo` and `whoami`, but for some reason the nircmd command doesn't seem to execute successfully. If I instead select "Run only when user is logged on" the task works.

The output of `whoami` is the same for both configurations, so I don't think it's a problem with user permissions. The user who's logged in when the command needs to run doesn't have permission to sleep the computer, so I don't think I can just create the task as them and have it configured to only run when they're logged in.

Does anyone have any ideas I can try? Perhaps a different command I can use to invoke S0 sleep?

(I've already tried `psshutdown` and `rundll32.exe`, and neither work because they only invoke S3 sleep which isn't supported by the computer's firmware, according to `powercfg -a`)

Edit: I've also tried using the following command but with the same results as nircmd.
`powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)`

Comment: Try setting the task to run as `SYSTEM` user and/or enable "run with highest privileges"? Windows is picky about what is allowed to hook into its power api (check system event log for errors like `User-mode process attempted to change the system state`). Also try the suggestions here for suspend/sleep: https://superuser.com/a/463652/673426. Or to only turn off the monitors, you can try this powershell (functionally the same as what you tried): https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/y4g267/how_to_turn_off_monitor/isfv8k5/

Comment: No luck with the `SYSTEM` user (confirmed to be running as SYSTEM with whom as part of the script) or toggling the "run with highest privileges" checkbox (tried with SYSTEM, Administrator, and unprivileged user. I also tried selecting "Run only when user is logged on selected" and highest privileges with the unprivileged user, and had no luck. 

I don't see any output like you mentioned in the System event log, though I do see messages when the computer is put to sleep.

I also tried with the other command I added in my post which seems to be the same as the powershell you linked.