# Windows 8 command for putting the computer into sleep

Tags: windows-8, powersave, sign-out

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I put the computer to sleep from Command Prompt/Run menu in Windows Vista?](https://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu-in-windows-vist)

With `shutdown /s /t 0`, I can shutdown immediately.

But which command I need to switch to put the computer to "sleep"?

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOH! YOU MEANT SUSPEND! Power saving mode means the power saving profile in Control Panel. I posted an answer to that. What you meant is "suspend". It's an entirely different thing Just post an answer to your question then. :)

Comment: oh sorry for that ... Can't post an answer, my account is to new, have to wait 8 hours I think. feel free to post the answer, will mark it as correct then