# How do you create a log off shortcut, a suspend one and a shutdown one?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I to create a logoff shortcut, a suspend one and a shutdown one? I know how to make the shortcut but when I add a hotkey they only work on the log off one and after a while it stops working all together. I do have administrative access on my home PC, but not at work; the shortcuts do work but I’m having the same issues.

I want to be able to drag it off my USB flash drive onto the desktop and for them to work. Also would they work hidden? Also I don't have access to <kbd>cmd</kbd> or <kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> at work.

Comment: keyboard shortcut or a desktop shortcut.  What is wrong with the shortcut(s) that already exist by default?

Comment: You can find your answers [here](http://superuser.com/a/42128/270195)

Comment: @Ramhound I'm creating a desktop shortcut and in the options i'm using hotkey.They work when you click on them but the hotkeys don't activate them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I put the computer to sleep from Command Prompt/Run menu?](http://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu)

Comment: @ramhound I don't have access to cmd or windows + r.

Comment: So that means you have no keyboard?  If you have no keyboard then you cannot do what you want.  If you make a ridiculous statement as "I have not looked at any possible duplicate but they don't have the same issue as me" you have to understand people are going to flag your question as a duplicate because you have exactly the same issue.

Comment: I have a keyboard, cmd is deactivated and shortcuts like windows + r are blocked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a batch file, e.g. *sleep.bat*, containing the following text:

> rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0

Make a shortcut to it (right-click, drag to a folder, and *Create shortcuts here*); name it as you like. Right-click on the new shortcut, select *Properties* and set the *Shortcut key* combination.

2. For *Logoff*, follow the steps above but use the following script:

> shutdown -l

3. [See MS *TechNet* guide to the *Shutdown* command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx) for *Shutdown*, *Hybrid Shutdown*, *Restart* etc.

**N.B.** *Hibernate* has been deprecated for Windows 8, but if you have it enabled in PowerCfg, then the first script may *Hibernate*, rather than sleep.

Comment: Would that work without admin rights?

Comment: *Logoff* should, but try the others to find out if you have sufficient privileges (they may also be set in Group Policies, so it's not possible to give a definitive answer).

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll try it at work tomorrow, I'll tell you if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shutdown.bat file from a text document with the following text:
`shutdown.exe -s -t 0`

**Save as** Shutdown.bat > then create a shortcut and place it on your desktop.

To create a restart button, change `-s` to `-r`;

to create a logoff button, change `-s -t 0` to `-l`.

Then create corresponding shortcuts for those and change the icons to something more suitable in the shortcut's properties.

**EDIT:** This works without administrative permission on all Windows systems as far as I am aware.

Comment: Would creating a .bat file work without administrative rights and .exe blocked?

Comment: As long as you execute them without admin permissions, yes.
I used these on my School's locked up computers back in the day.

Comment: Ok, i'll also tell you if they work. If it's hidden and i create a hotkey as f4 would it work?

Comment: I assume so, yes.