# Use Windows Task Scheduler To Put Windows To Sleep Without Batch File

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

How can I use Task Scheduler to put Windows 10 to sleep at a specific time without using a batch file?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu

Answer (score 7):

Set up your time in Task Scheduler's Triggers window as normal. On the General tab, it's probably easiest to make the task run as `SYSTEM`, and run whether the user is logged in or not. Highest privileges are not necessary.

Since `rundll32` is [deprecated and treacherous in general](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643), we'll use PowerShell to invoke the sleep function correctly. Set the *Program/script* field to `powershell.exe`. Put this in the *Add arguments* field:

```
-command add-type -assemblyname System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState([System.Windows.Forms.PowerState]::Suspend, $false, $false)
```

The `add-type` command imports the Forms assembly, which contains [a managed `SetSuspendState` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setsuspendstate(v=vs.110).aspx). The second command calls that method, putting the computer to sleep but allowing wake events to exit sleep. (If you don't want wake events to keep working, change the last `$false` to `$true`.)

Comment: This works fine for sleeping, but how can I wake it from this sleep? Also with task scheduler.

Comment: @AlexBartiş Though I haven't tested it, [this HTG guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/) looks promising.

Comment: thanks, I've tried it before asking you, and it doesn't work for me. I'm on the latest W10 Home Edition, and it doesn't work if I manually put it to sleep or if I use your task to put it to sleep.

Comment: @AlexBartiş Hmm, in that case, I would suggest asking a new question with that information, as you have done. Hopefully somebody knows the answer.

Comment: If anyone's still interested, here's an alternative way of scheduling. https://www.groovypost.com/howto/schedule-wake-sleep-windows-automatically/

Comment: Note, for windows 10 this method has same bug not having the standby feature so it won't wake your computer if you also schedule that on your task scheduler. Use Sysinternals Pstools : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360306/sleep-via-shortcut-causes-schedule-tasks-to-not-wake-computer

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new task.
2. Decide how you want the General tab to be set (I recommend selecting "Run whether user is logged on or not").
3. I chose "Run with highest privileges", but this depends on your requirements.
4. Create a Trigger that describes when you want the task to run.
5. Create a new Action--this is the key step: The Action must be "Start a program".

The "Program/script" value should be: rundll32.exe 
The "Add arguments (optional):" value should be: powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState sleep
The "Start in (optional):" value should be left empty.

**IT IS IMPORTANT TO OBSERVE THE CASE OF THE "SetSuspendState" argument! "setsuspendstate" won't work!**

6. Save your task and test-run it.

Comment: **Danger!** `rundll32` is [deprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643). Also, `sleep` is not a valid argument to [`SetSuspendState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373201(v=vs.85).aspx), which only takes three Booleans. Therefore, passing a string works only by chance, and probably demolishes the function's stack.