# Schedule Windows 10 Sleep and Wake

Tags: windows-10, sleep, windows-task-scheduler, wake-up

I have a Windows 10 Home Edition tablet (2 in 1 actually) and I want to use the tablet part as a display for an IP camera. This means I need it on and power connected all through the day but not at night. For this task, I want to schedule it to go to sleep at lets say 11 PM and wake up at 7 AM.

Is there any way to accomplish this, maybe using Task Scheduler?

Edit: I got Sleep to work with the answer here: [Use Windows Task Scheduler To Put Windows To Sleep Without Batch File](https://superuser.com/questions/1069944/use-windows-task-scheduler-to-put-windows-to-sleep-without-batch-file/1069952?noredirect=1#comment1879719_1069952) however I still need to find out how to wake at a given time.

Comment: Great that you got this to work, and thanks for closing the loop on your question.  The site's Q&A format relies on questions containing just question information, and all solution information being in answers.  It would be helpful if you could move your edit to an answer.  Include the gist of the solution so that it's self-contained, and use the link for attribution and further reading.  You can accept your own answer to indicate that the problem is solved.

Comment: @fixer1234 it's not a solution. I was searching for both a way to put it to sleep and wake it, but I didn't find yet.

Comment: If anyone's still interested, here's an alternative way of scheduling. 

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/schedule-wake-sleep-windows-automatically/

Comment: I found this, and worked for me! [Schedule Windows 10 to Wake From Sleep Automatically](https://www.technipages.com/schedule-windows-10-to-wake-from-sleep-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way to create a scheduled task that just wakes the computer up. 
The only non-deprecated action a scheduled task can perform is running a program/script.

However, like in many cases, there's a workaround. You can configure a scheduled task to wake the computer up to perform the task. If the action is, for example, "open a cmd an immediately close it", a scheduled task can wake the computer up at a specific time.

It sounds as if you already know [how to create a scheduled task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx), so I'll just skip to the interesting parts.

After configuring what time and how frequently you want the task to run, the action you want to add is *"start a program"*. Under *"Program/script"*, write  `"/c exit"`. This is a simple command that will end cmd/powershell sessions.

Open the scheduled task's properties. In the *"general"* tab, mark *"Run whether user is logged on or not"*, for obvious reasons.

Now all that's left is to make the scheduled task wake the computer up if need be. In the properties, and under *"conditions"* mark *"wake the computer to run this task"*. You might also want to remove the mark on *"Start the task only if the computer is on AC power"*, if you're using a laptop. There's no need to give the task any special privileges.

And there you go - a new scheduled task that wakes the computer up whenever you want.

Comment: Thanks for this @stav and sorry for the late reply. This I found in a tutorial on HTG before posting the question, but it doesn't work with the way I put it to sleep, posted in the original question. Maybe then you could provide a better way of putting it to sleep?

Comment: Widows 10 : Windows 10 requires you to choose Run Only with the following User Logged on if it is an interactive program.  Sort of makes sense, but it is a change.  "cmd.exe /c exit" no longer works as it is apparently is considered interactive.  It will run a batch file with "Echo Hi > Wake.log", which it apparently doesn't consider interactive. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-task-scheduler-doesnt-wake-the-computer/57975139-36a9-4398-9259-38172aae023b

Comment: I have recently failed with the "cmd.exe /c exit". The behavior is weird. The machine wakes up on schedule and I can remote into it - but it then goes back to sleep after 5 minutes. Despite me being active on the desktop. Maybe I just need to change the command I run.