# Windows 10 Auto Login

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, windows-10-v1607

I have been trying to find a way for windows 10 to auto login just once after its scheduled to power on at 6:00 AM, then i have a working script to autologoff idle users after 45 minutes of inactivity.

I have tried to look for solution but all i came up to was that the computer would autologin on every reboot.

So has anyone came across anything similiar to autologin a specific user just once lets say at 6:10 AM?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to do an actual shutdown? If you did a `sleep` or a `hibernate` instead of shutdown, then you would not need to worry about auto login. https://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu#42128

Comment: Actually I need to shutdown the computers but I'll look into that thx