# Why I can't sleep my PC with a batch file in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, sleep

Earlier I had Windows 8.1 installed on my PC. Then I installed Windows 10. I used to sleep the PC with the following code when I was using 8.1.
[image]

but it doesn't work with 10; a CMD window flashes only for a second and nothing happen.
How to overcome this issue?

edit: for @AFH 's request
[image]

Comment: I don't see an extensioon `.bat` or `.cmd` to really execute the file with cmd.exe?

Comment: Type the command in an interactive `cmd` to see if there are any error messages; or add a `pause` to the batch file.

Comment: Are you right-clicking and running as admin?

Comment: @Appleoddity I tried that but no progress

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this caused above problem, but I'm posting this answer as I found the answer from another person.
I corrected this issue and another one (not being able to rotate the screen with ctrl+alt+→, ←, ↓) by installing display driver **for Windows 10**. The motherboard's CD came with drivers which supported only for up to Windows 8, so it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

The command rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0 for sleep is correct - however, it will hibernate instead of sleep if you don't turn the hibernation off.

Here's how to do that:

Go to the Start Menu and open an elevated Command Prompt by typing cmd.exe, right clicking and choosing Run as administrator. Type the following command:

powercfg -hibernate off

I got this from [How can I put the computer to sleep from Command Prompt/Run menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu) . Do your research.

Comment: You say  “it will hibernate instead of sleep if you don't turn the hibernation off” — but the OP indicates that neither happens. And there’s no need to be snarky.