# Hibernation without an elevated command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, hibernate

In this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu) you can see how to put the Windows in a half-hibernated situation but not only does it not **fully** hibernate but also it requires an elevated command prompt but if you even login as guest account you can put the computer in hibernation through the GUI (assuming hibernation is enabled)

Now I was wondering if I could put the Windows in actual hibernation without admin privileges?