# How do I put a Windows 11 PC to sleep over RDP?

Tags: remote-desktop, sleep, windows-11

If I try to use any of the GUI options on the remote PC (Start button, Start button right-click menu, Ctrl-Alt-End screen, Alt-F4 on desktop), nothing happens. And the `shutdown` command-line utility doesn't have a flag for sleep, only for hibernation.

Comment: Try using powercfg to put the computer to sleep. I think that might work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I put the computer to sleep from Command Prompt/Run menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu)