# (Windows 11) NodeJS, set computer to sleep, but it hibernates?

Tags: sleep, node.js

Trying to run a command in NodeJS that simply puts my computer to sleep, but the command ended up hibernating it?

```
exec("rundll32.exe powrprof.dll, SetSuspendState Sleep");
```

By sleep I mean, when I wake it up, it instantly comes back to the Windows User Login screen, however when I used the command above, when I woke the computer back up, it came back to the BIOS screen. My session was still saved but I want it to instantly go to the Windows User Login screen, so I think it actually hibernated my computer.

What's the correct command to get it to sleep properly?

Comment: Take a look at [How can I put the computer to sleep from Command Prompt/Run menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu).

Answer (score 0):

Psshutdown is the solution:

```
exec("psshutdown.exe -d -t 0", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log('stdout is:' + stdout)
    console.log('stderr is:' + stderr)
    console.log('error is:' + err)
  }).on('exit', code => console.log('final exit code is', code))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please share the actual code you used to solve your problem so it can be a useful reference for others who come along with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

hibernate the local computer. as below steps:

- step1.

  switch hibernate command: `powercfg.exe /H on`
- step2.

  `shutdown.exe /h`

Comment: But that will hibernate it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).