# Find cause of startup BSOD connected with complete battery discharge

Tags: windows-10, battery, bsod, shutdown

I get the following issue on my [Lenovo Yoga C940-15IRH](https://www.lenovo.com/ch/en/laptops/yoga/yoga-2-in-1-series/Lenovo-Yoga-C940-15IRH/p/88YGC901298?orgRef=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) laptop (i7-9750H, Geforce 1650 Max-Q, 16GB RAM, 4K display):

- I work on battery, and turn the PC off (Shut down) with the battery well over 60%
- When I turn the PC on again, I immediately get a BSOD ( VIDEO_DXGKRNL_FATAL_ERROR (0x00000113)) on startup. The PC won't turn on again on battery.
- When I connect to AC, the PC will start normally, but battery level is completely down on 1%.

What I suspect is, that the PC won't shut down completely, and continue to consume battery even if shut down. Then, on restart, a too low battery level will cause the BSOD. I suspect this as on a previous BIOS version, the PC would not correctly go into sleep mode, overheat and drain the battery.

Is there a way to verify this? The laptop is still in warranty, but I'd like to track down the issue as closely as possible before contacting Lenovo support.

I've done a `powercfg /batteryreport` but it is not of any use, as it will not track the battery discharge:
[image: Battery Report]
On the above image, the BSOD occurs `2023-03-23 12:41:00`, just before the PC is powered on on AC, with 1% battery

The BSOD error code is the following:
`The bugcheck was: 0x00000113 (0x0000000000000019, 0x0000000000000002, 0x00000000000010de, 0x0000000000001f91).`

An alternate explanation would be that the battery rapidly discharges upon the BSOD, but this would denote a hardware failure which should cause much bigger problems.

So, my questions:

- Is there a way to make sure whether the system gets shut down completely?
- is there a way to know whether the battery discharges while the system is off, because some component is still active?
- is there a way to know if the BSOD is caused by a low battery level?
- other possibilities to track down the issue?

Comment: You might want to check the Windows event log for kernel power events. Also, if it happens fairly consistently I’m not sure why you wouldn’t just shut it down, wait say 5 hours, boot it up then see whether it is responsive and what the battery level is like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a faulty mainboard. Changing the mainboard (in warranty) resolved the issue.

Lenovo supporto determined a mainboard issue, as the following steps did not change the problem:

- reset the battery with a complete discharge-charge cycle
- tested that the battery discharged nominally until 5% while the PC was running
- updated all drivers through the OEM's webiste
- update of the Intel chipset firmware
- even when booting into BIOS, the PC died after a few seconds with the battery completely discharged.

Answer (score 1):

It is a battery and gets used up with use.

Two approaches:

**(A) Battery Reset**

(1) Charge the battery fully.
(2) Unplug the AC Adapter.
(3) Allow to run down to 10 %
(4) Plug in the adapter and then restart the computer.
(5) Allow to fully charge.

See if Reset helps.

See if this allows you to update BIOS.

**(B) Replace the Battery.**

After step 5, run Lenovo Vantage and look at Battery Health. If it will not hold a charge, then it is time to replace the Battery.

You may wish to have the machine serviced at this point for hardware issues prior to replacing the battery.

**Followup note**:  Dr Battery (Amazon) has new FRU (Field Replaceable Unit) replacement batteries for numerous Thinkpads. I put a new battery in my 10-year old X230 and it is working well.

Comment: I meant Step 5 in Part A  . You said in your question that if the battery is at roughly 1/2 and you shut down,  and start up, battery is at 0.  So either something wrong with the battery or perhaps the machine needs service.

Comment: Surprisingly, this got me straight to the issue. The battery is damaged and will rapidly discharge when it goes under 40%. No chance anymore of getting to 10%

Comment: I added a note.  Dr Battery (Amazon) can supply new FRU replacement batteries for numerous ThinkPads.

Comment: Thanks, @John I'll try to get a OEM part through Lenovo support, given that I still have a year of warranty left. Might not be the cheapest option, but I prefer original parts

Comment: It depends on the age of the laptop and if Lenovo has original batteries in good condition. Batteries do not store well.  There are now manufacturers putting new cells in the original (type) plastic package and they have worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

- Be sure you shut down the PC *correctly*. There are a few choices:

  - Complete shutdown, equivalent to entering `shutdown /s /t /0` in <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> edit bar
  - Hibernation, equivalent to `shutdown /h` in <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> edit bar (Note that [hibernation must be enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/disable-and-re-enable-hibernation).)
  - Sleep, which can be done through closing the lid or otherwise as set in *Power Options*. There is no simple command to do so, but Sysinternals' [*shutdown.exe*](https://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu) lets you do so.

  **N.B.:** The first two options use *no* power (except for a a bit *some* PC's use for battery equalization, network connectivity or anti-theft purpose, etc.). **Sleep is not a full shutdown**, and keeps the CPU alive at reduced level, depleting the battery. Do not leave the PC in sleep on battery for an extended time.

  To be sure the machine is shut correctly, make a script for each command, and add shortcuts to each; and/or set it in *Power Options* for actions such as clicking power button or closing lid.
- A battery that has been discharged to **1%** has likely been damaged. Though it may show as being fully charged (as measured by *voltage*) when plugged into an outlet, it can no longer provide sufficient *current* to keep the machine running. The battery may need to be replaced.

  To avoid such damage in the future, leave a safety margin to force hibernation on low battery.

  [image: Battery safety margin]
- Finally, some laptops drain power even when off. If the PC will not be used for weeks, remove the battery, if it's easy to do, or plug in the device weekly to prevent depletion below 40%.

Comment: There might be something about the "full shutdown", it reminded me to turn off fast startup in the control panels' system power options (although I doubt it makes any differnece). For the rest, this doesn't really attempt to answer my question.