# Sleep shortcut in win7

Tags: windows-7, sleep, power

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the command to use to put your computer to sleep (not hibernate)?](https://superuser.com/questions/39584/what-is-the-command-to-use-to-put-your-computer-to-sleep-not-hibernate)

When I try to create a sleep shortcut in windows 7 x64 using this code:

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0.1.0
```

Then Windows hibernates instead of going to sleep.

I don't want to turn off hibernate as I do still want to be able to use it.

How do I make this work to make my computer go to sleep?

Answer (score 17):

Do *not* call these functions from `rundll32`. They were not designed to, and if you do, you are basically [passing garbage as arguments](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043).

You can use [PsShutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown) to suspend the computer (`psshutdown -d`) or write a tiny program of your own ([someone already did](https://www.spinellis.gr/blog/20081006/)<sup>1</sup>).

---

<sup>1</sup> [Compiled version.](http://ompldr.org/vYTZvOA/SetSystemPowerState.zip)

Comment: How do you tell that a function was not designed for Rundll32?

Comment: @accolade: You read its documentation. The compatible functions have a [very specific](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q164787) signature (HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow), and usually their documentation explicitly mentions rundll32. All other functions are not compatible.

Comment: @grawity: Thanks! How did you find the documentation for `Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState`? (I had no success with two quick googlings.)

Comment: @accolade: Search for [the function name](https://www.google.com/search?q=setsuspendstate) only, and it'll usually be the first or second [result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373201(v=vs.85).aspx). (The DLL name is not part of normal usage; this is probably why you found no results with it.) Since it is part of Windows, adding the `msdn` keyword may help as well.