# How can I put my computer to "fast sleep" via command-line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the command to use to put your computer to sleep (not hibernate)?](https://superuser.com/questions/39584/what-is-the-command-to-use-to-put-your-computer-to-sleep-not-hibernate)

I'm trying to set up a batch file I would run via task scheduler to put my computer to sleep at a given time, but I can't get exactly what I want ...

When I press the sleep button on my keyboard (or click sleep in the power menu), the computer goes to sleep and when I power it up again, it only takes about 4-5 second until I am at the logon screen.

When I try to do the same via command line, when I power it up again, it goes through the POST screen and I have to wait at the "resuming windows" screen. How can I get the same result in command line?

I already tried `Rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep` and `Rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Standby` without the result I was expecting...

PS : I'm on Win7 x64